# error al llamar a build.create

Tags: android, android-studio, alertdialog, diálogo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He personalizado un dialog, pero como el AlertDialog.Builder no tiene dismiss() le quité el builder y ahora no acepta el llamado del create por error de vesrión.

```
public AlertDialog DespachoAct() {
    final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DespachoDActivity.this).show();
    LayoutInflater inflater = DespachoDActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_despacho, null);
    builder.setView(v);
    builder.show();
    cb1 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cb1) ;
    txtsoles = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtsoles);
    txtobs2 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtobs2);
    act = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnactualizar2);
    can = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btncancelar);
    act.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DownloadTask2 up = new DownloadTask2();
                    up.execute();
                    new DownloadTask().execute("");
                    builder.dismiss();
                }
            }
    );
    can.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    builder.dismiss();
                }
            }
    );
    /////////// sale : call requires api level 21 (current min is 19)android.app.Dialog#create return builder.create();
     return builder.create();
}
```

.........................

después de hacer varios intentos lo solucioné. a ver si les sirve :)

```
public AlertDialog DespachoAct(){
    final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DespachoDActivity.this).create();
    LayoutInflater inflater = DespachoDActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_despacho, null);
    builder.setView(v);
    builder.show();
    cb1 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cb1) ;
    cb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isChecked = cb1.isChecked();
            if(isChecked){
                b="1";
            }
            else
            {
                b="";
            }
        }
    });
    txtsoles = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtsoles);
    txtobs2 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtobs2);
    txtrecibo = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtrecibo);
    act = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnactualizar2);
    can = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btncancelar);
    act.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (b=="1" && txtsoles.getText().toString().length()>0 && txtobs2.getText().toString().length()>0
                            && txtrecibo.getText().toString().length()>0){


                        DownloadTask2 up = new DownloadTask2();
                        up.execute();
                        new DownloadTask().execute("");
                        builder.dismiss();

                    }

                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Se encontraron datos vacios ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
    );
    can.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    builder.dismiss();
                }
            }
    );
    return builder;
}
```

Comment: En la imágen te dice donde puede estar el error, necesitas versión de android mínima a 21 y la tienes a 19, ctrl+f1 sobre la linea marcada con error, da más información, o hasta alt+intro

Answer (score 0):

Estas trabajando con 2 objetos distintos.

El **builder** como lo dice su nombre tiene como responsabilidad configurar los parametros del dialog y devolver una nueva instancias utilizando el método `build()`.

**IMPORTANTE**: `build()` solo genera el dialogo, para que este se vea debes llamar a el metodo `show()` del dialog.

El **Dialog** en sí es el objeto que muestra dilogo en pantalla, el cual tiene los métodos `show()` y `dismiss()` para mostrar y ocultar respectivamente.

Comment: gracias, pero ya lo solucioné hace tiempo.

Comment: por favor especifica la respuesta correcta y marca la pregunta como respondida. gracias.